# Why does GCC -Wselector and -Wundeclared-selector warn about declared selectors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcc, warnings

The description of GCC’s `-Wselector` and `-Wundeclared-selector` options make them sound like wonderful programming tools to guard against typos in Objective-C `@selector()` expressions.

However, upon enabling them on my codebase, I get warnings like this:

```
Unimplemented selector 'reloadData'
```

pointing to lines like this:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This line of code is fairly common in our codebase. Data is loaded asynchronously, and once it is loaded, the above line of code is used to signal the `UITableView` to reload (on the main thread, since calling UIKit from background threads is a bad idea).

My question is multi-part:

1. Is the above line of code incorrect in some way? Is there a better pattern for signalling `UITableView`, on the main thread, to reload its data?
2. Why does GCC warn about this when there is clearly a declaration in `UITableView.h` for the `reloadData` selector?
3. Is there a way to get GCC to warn about undeclared selectors without causing it to complain about selectors which clearly are declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I'm a fan of `-Wundeclared-selector`. I haven't seen this problem crop up. Did you `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in this particular file (or in your .pch)? I can't reproduce this problem in a simple program with `-Wundeclared-selector`.

- Create single-view iOS project w/ Storyboard
- Drop UITableView on main view. Wire to `tableView` IBOutlet
- Turn on "Undeclared Selector" warning
- Put your line of code into `viewDidLoad`
- Build

Change `reloadData` to `reloadDat` and I get the warning (as expected):

```
Undeclared selector 'reloadDat'
```

You say you're getting "Unimplemented selector 'reloadData'." Is that really the warning, or did you mean to type "Undeclared?"

Comment: I’m literally getting `Unimplemented selector 'reloadData'`. Of note is that I have both `-Wselector` and `-Wundeclared-selector` enabled. The descriptions are written badly, but don’t suggest that `-Wselector` should behave the way I’m seeing. However, I’ll test with just `-Wundeclared-selector` and see what happens.

Comment: The issue is purely with `-Wselector` and not with `-Wundeclared-selector`. I’ve turned on the latter. The documentation on these warnings could be improved!